# datagridview highlighted row not changing color using a comboboxcell

Tags: datagridview, colors, combobox, row, datagridviewcomboboxcell

[image]The row color is changing for all types of cell controls, ie textboxcell, checkboxell, however combobox cell remains elusive. Do I need to roll my own using a drawmode or is it just a property that is going to forever elude me?

I am just instantiating a new column cell among many and the color of the cell is stuck on grey until the user at runtime select the dropdown list. Below I am using the autogenerated columns in vs2015 to create the cmbbx.
DataGridViewComboBoxCell CBOX_CELL = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
row.Cells.Add(CBOX_CELL);

so i cant do two things
1. get the combobox cell to highlight when its row is selected
2. the style is stuck on gray so users have a hard time seeing what row is selected and i have many of these comboboxes

Comment: If the `DataGridView`s selection mode is set to `FullRowSelect`, then… If the combo box column’s `FlatStyle` is set to `Flat` or `Popup` the combo boxes will be highlighted as other cells are. Just guessing.

Comment: Hi, I already tried this after some research. I am going to try again just to make sure!

Comment: So I tried again, I even fiddled with backcolor, the datagridcolor. It may require some custom class that inherits.

Comment: I do not think changing the color is going to make any difference. You may want to show what you have tried and what is not working as expected.

Comment: High JohnG, I tried...DataGridViews selection mode is set to FullRowSelect, combo box column’s FlatStyle is set to Flat, and nothing changes. I must say i am creating these columns with their combobox cell atdesign time, im not using datafable.

Comment: Unfortunately, without some code or a picture of what is not working. Speculation is about all you will get.